# Java overloading methods with generic and a collection of a generic

Tags: java, generics, overloading

Having an interface with these two methods:

```
void add(T result);
void add(List<T> result);
```

I was expecting Java on runtime will call the appropriated method:

```
final U result = getResult();
myInterface.add(result);
```

If `U` is a list I thought second method would be called, but always the first one is called.
Why this behavior? What should be the correct way to achieve that?

Comment: of what type is `myInterface` - what is `T`, what is `U` in your current context?

Comment: The simplest solution would be naming. `add(T)` and `addAll(List<T>)`. Its how [`List` resolves this issue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-).

Comment: @luk2302 At runtime `T` will be replaced with `Object`.  So passing a `List` could use either method.  Not sure about compile time.

Comment: @luk2302 let's say `T` is a `String` and `U` is a `List<String>`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen at runtime that is true, I am wondering about compile-time and it should be **very** clear what method will get called if U and T are known.

Comment: @ilopezluna if your `myInterface` is of type `YourInterface<List<String>>` the first method would get called, if it is of type `YourInterface<String>` I would expect the second to get called. If U == T then I would expect the first method would be called no matter if they are lists or lists of lists or simply String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the compile-time type of `U`. If `U` is unbounded, the compiler can't determine whether it's a `List` or a `String` or your aunt Hilda.
So the "ungenericized" code becomes:

```
final Object result = getResult();
myInterface.add(result);
```

However, if `U` is actually `<U extends List<?>>`, the compiler can narrow down the possibilities (with your help) and the "ungenericized" code becomes:

```
final List result = getResult();
myInterface.add(result);
```

giving you the expected overloaded method call.